# Google Cloud Storage .Net Client Bulk Upload

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I am uploading files to cloud storage using the .net client.
at the moment am uploading files one by one like

```
StorageClient client = StorageClient.Create();
foreach(file in files)
{
    client.UploadObject(bucketName, uploadLocation, contentType, file);
}
```

But I couldn't find any way to bulk upload files. Is there any way to upload files in bulk ?

Comment: I am just trying to help here and have scarcity of time to give you detailed reply, but I found something. Have you checked about Performing resumable uploads? Please check this, right now I got hold on of JSON API, but I guess you can use that in your code. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads?cloudshell=false Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You are effectively bulk uploading; you're just uploading each file serially

If you're looking for a method that you give `files` to and it handles the entire upload, I'm unsure that this exists.

You can run the uploads in parallel using threads or equivalent.

You'll want to ensure that you can resume failed uploads (uploading multiple files increases the likelihood of failure), see [Create Object Uploader](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient#Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_StorageClient_CreateObjectUploader_Google_Apis_Storage_v1_Data_Object_System_IO_Stream_Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_UploadObjectOptions_)

You'll need to self-manage resuming on failures.

It's possible that there are libraries that implement this abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are searching for a way to upload a large number of files at once in Google Cloud Storage. However, there is no direct method to handle the entire upload. If you have a large number of files to upload you can perform a parallel multi-threaded/multi-processing copy. The following steps are to be followed:

```
1.Instantiation of a StorageClient object.
2.Specifying the parallelization options.
3.Getting a list of filenames from my upload folder and storing the names of the files.
4.Getting a list of files in the cloud.
5.Using the Parallel Foreach.
6.calling the UploadObject method from the Google Cloud Storage client library.
```

You can also refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@asadikhan/uploading-csv-files-to-google-cloud-storage-using-c-net-9eaa951eabf2) for more details on the above methods.